# SharePoint (MOSS 2007) successful forms authentication redirects to machine name

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication

I have a SharePoint site extended for forms authentication.  The Active Directory site is `example.com` and the forms authentication site is `forms.example.com`.  When I type my (forms) username/password I get redirected (302) to the machine name (`moss-01`) like so: `http://moss-01/`.  If I type `http://forms.example.com/` into the address bar I am again redirected to `http://moss-01/`.

Expected behavior is successful authentication into the forms site: `http://forms.example.com/Pages/Default.aspx`

Why am I being redirected to the machine name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with your zones and Alternate Access Mapping (AAM).

Start here: http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/06/what-every-sharepoint-administrator-needs-to-know-about-alternate-access-mappings-part-1.aspx

Comment: I am familiar with AAMs.  The link provided talks about solving problems with reverse proxies.  That is not my problem.  Parts 2 and 3 of that article don't seem to apply either.

Comment: You were correct - it's an AAM problem.  It was part 2 of that blog post that tipped me off - and makes me want to slap myself - I was accessing the site via https when I should have been using http.  I imagine that If I want to use https I'll need to add the AAMs.  Thanks!

Comment: part 2 link: http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/19/what-every-sharepoint-administrator-needs-to-know-about-alternate-access-mappings-part-2-of-3.aspx